# Create analyzer with Edge N Gram analyzer and char filter which replaces space with new line

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, tokenize, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have below type of text coming in.
`foo bar`, `hello world` etc.
I created an analyzer using Edge NGram tokenizer and using the analyze api it creates below token.

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "f",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "fo",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "foo",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "b",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "ba",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "token": "bar",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

But when in my code I pass the text "foo bar" to method *tokenStream*, it create below tokens for *foo bar*.

> f, fo, foo, foo , foo b, foo ba, foo bar.

This is causing the mismatch in the tokens returned by *analyze* api. I want to know how can I *add a char filter which removes the space in the text and apply Edge NGram tokenizer on individual terms in the text.*

So, In the *foo bar* example, it should create below token. when I call *tokenStream* method.

> f, fo, foo, b, ba, bar.

I tried adding the char filter to my java code of create the analyzer. Below is the code of it.

```
@Override
    public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        NormalizeCharMap normalizeCharMap = new NormalizeCharMap();
        normalizeCharMap.add(" ", "\\u2424");
        Reader replaceDots = new MappingCharFilter(normalizeCharMap, reader);
        TokenStream result = new EdgeNGramTokenizer(replaceDots, EdgeNGramTokenizer.DEFAULT_SIDE, 1, 30);
        return result;
    }
```

But it takes `lu2424` as it as. Also please let me know if my code of Analyzer is correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have tested using the analyze API is an [edge-ngram **token filter**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html), which is different from an [edge-ngram **tokenizer**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html).

In your code, you need to replace `EdgeNGramTokenizer` by `EdgeNGramTokenFilter` if you want to have the same behavior in your code as you tested with the analyze API.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. but do you mean in your first line that instead of token filter, I used the tokenizer and I need to replace it with the edgeN gram filter?

Comment: What you want is an edge-ngram token filter (what you tested using the analyze API), but what you used in your code is an edge-ngram tokenizer. See my second sentence

Comment: But then analyze api should use the analyzer which I created and in my code I used the edge-ngram tokenizer not filter, then how come it's giving the response of the filter? that I am not getting.

Comment: We're not seeing what you sent to the analyze API.

Comment: my bad, will update the question with it. Also I can't directly use the token filter and need to use at least 1 tokenizer before I pass the token stream to token filter. In my case should I use the keyword tokenizer, as I don't want anything espical and just want to token text `foo bar` as `f,fo,foo,foo , foo b, foo ba, foo bar`.

Comment: You said you wanted `f, fo, foo, b, ba, bar.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178428/discussion-between-amit-khandelwal-and-val).