# Custom analyzer in java, using edgeNGram token filter

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, tokenize

This is in continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930012/create-analyzer-with-edge-n-gram-analyzer-and-char-filter-which-replaces-space-w). I am using Lucene 3.6.1 and want to create a custom analyzer which creates tokens like below:-

I/P text :- `foo bar`

Tokens :- `f,fo,foo,b,ba,bar`

I/P text :- `HEllo 123`

Tokens:- `h,he,hel,hell,hello,1,12,123`.

Basically, it converts the text to lower case and then uses the edge n-gram token filter.

Below is my java code for the custom analyzer.

```
@Override
    public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        TokenStream stream = new KeywordTokenizer(reader);
        TokenStream result = new EdgeNGramTokenFilter(stream, EdgeNGramTokenFilter.Side.FRONT, 1, 30);
        //OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute = result.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
        CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = result.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        try {
            result.reset();
            while (result.incrementToken()) {
                //int startOffset = offsetAttribute.startOffset();
                //int endOffset = offsetAttribute.endOffset();
                System.out.println(charTermAttribute.toString());
            }
            result.end();
            result.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But it returns below tokens for `foo bar`.

```
f
fo
foo
foo 
foo b
foo ba
foo bar
```

Let me know what I am missing in my code.

Comment: ... then uses the edge n-gram **token filter** (not tokenizer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `StandardTokenizer` and not the `KeywordTokenizer`. The latter will simply treat the whole input as a single token, while the former will lowercase and split the input into multiple tokens.

So change this:

```
    TokenStream stream = new KeywordTokenizer(reader);
```

to this:

```
    TokenStream stream = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
```

Comment: Thanks @Val.. you are just awesome.

Comment: you are super fast on SO.